# Reorder ListView by wordCount through RTF files

Tags: c#, listview, search, rtf

So I have a listView that references a series of rtf files saved to my disc. When you click on a list item it will display the contents of the rtf file in a RichTextBox.

I want to implement a TextBox that will reorder the list based on the number of times the TextBox's string appears in each rtf file (ideally excluding rtfs that don't have the string altogether)

Anyone have any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: I've edited your title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/158100) where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably build a list of the strings along with a count, starting at 0, when you go through the files, and just increment it whenever that word is found. Then you can order your list based on the counts it gives.